# How to start a VM through Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, virtual-machine

I am looking for an automated way to start a virtual machine in Windows Powershell. Does anyone have any input on how I may accomplish this task?

I have looked around and have been unsuccessful so far with finding a way to do so.

I thought that this was a standard cmdlet form powershell, but I am beginning to think that I am wrong on that assumption.

I have looked into using (If i am understanding this correctly) PowerCLIs `Start-VM` and am having issues saying that I am currently not connected to the server, but I don't believe I have a server to connect to (unless I am thinking about this the wrong way). I am just trying to do this locally right now to check to see if it is a valid VM to use.

**--- EDIT ---**

I am looking to do this with VMware, but really I could use Windows if that means doing this without spending any money.

I am also using powershell 2.0 and it does not seem that Start-VM is an option for me to use unfortunately...

**--- EDIT 2 ---**

Can anybody further explain how WMI works? I am relatively new using powershell and I have never had to use WMI before.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You don't mention which virtualization solution you're using.  VMWare?  Hyper-V?  Xen?  VirtualBox?

Comment: @mikekol - I edited my question above to answer your question... I guess it would be helpful to point out that kind of information...

Comment: I've actually written a [blog post about this](http://torywaterman.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-powershell-to-shutdown-apply.html). This is for remoting in, shutting down, applying snapshots, and starting them... you'd only need that last bit. This was only tested with Hyper-V on Server 2008 R2 but it might work for you. I've posted an answer with the relevant bit.

Comment: Do you have vCenter? Or just vSphere?

Comment: @Entbark - I do not have either. I have Acronis Backup and Recovery, Powershell 4.0, and Kaseya to do all of my work. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you hosting your virtual machine? If you are using a VMware product, which product?

Answer (score 1):

Extension of my comment above... this code snippet should do what you need:

```
$VM = gwmi MSVM_ComputerSystem -filter "ElementName='serverName'" -namespace "root\virtualization" -computername "."
$VM.requeststatechange(2)
```

WMI is pretty dated though (PowerShell 1.0), this works for me on Server 2008 R2. You should add what OS you're working with. If you're on Server 2012, it's a lot easier. Just use [Start-VM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848589.aspx) (PowerShell 4.0):

```
Start-VM –Name VMName
```

Arguably a lot easier than using WMI.

Comment: I am edited the version of powershell that i am using (which is 2.0). I do not believe that Start-VM is an option for me unfortunately. Would WMI be my only option?

Comment: You could also use the PSHyper-V module from CodePlex.  It wraps up a lot of the WMI stuff for you.  https://pshyperv.codeplex.com/

Comment: @tnw - Would you be able to possibly help me out by elaborating what you are doing with your script? I am fairly new to PS scripting especially using WMI and I do not really understand what you are doing with your parameters.

Comment: @tnw - I also wanted to ask if Start-VM was something that is just available in Powershell 4.0 (like on windows 7)? I was looking around here http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/photostory/2240178466/The-five-best-Windows-PowerShell-v3-commands-every-admin-should-know/5/Changing-state-with-the-Stop-VM-and-Start-VM-cmdlets and it seems to be something that should work. However, after updating my Powreshell to 4.0 in seems to still not be available. I have checked to see if it updated to the correct version and it has. Any ideas?

Comment: Start-VM is a cmdlet from the PowerCLI snap-in from VMware.

Comment: @Entbark - If I were to use the PowerCLI snap-in from VMware, it comes up with an error asking for servers. I do not exactly understand why this is... I am just trying to do this on my Local VM to test a possible solution to this. Do you have any input about this?

Comment: You need to explain how your VM is hosted before we can assist you.